# invalid character value for cast Error occurs while sending string over to MS Access DB using uCanAccess drivers

Tags: java, sql, ms-access

I want to store the name value into the database the datatype for the name column is Short Text, but i always get an error as invalid character value for cast.

I already tried using the normal Statement class instead of PreparedStatement but i got the same issue.
Here's the code for the same

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println(cid);
    id = Integer.parseInt(pid.getText());
    name = pname.getText();
    quant = Integer.parseInt(quantity.getText());
    pr = Integer.parseInt(price.getText());
    tx = Integer.parseInt(tax.getText());
    System.out.println(name);
    String query = "Insert into Product values ( ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ?)";
    try {
        Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://src\\ERP_System\\Database\\ERPdb.accdb");
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
        stmt.setInt(1,id);
        stmt.setInt(2,cid);
        System.out.println("Hello");
        stmt.setString(3, name); // error is triggerred by this statement
        System.out.println("Hello2");
        stmt.setInt(3,pr);
        stmt.setInt(4,tx);
        stmt.setInt(5,quant);
        ResultSet rs;
        stmt.execute();    
        System.out.println("Hello3");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

```
I keep getting the error as 

net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.4 data exception: invalid character value for cast
 at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessPreparedStatement.setString(UcanaccessPreparedStatement.java:742)
 at ERP_System.AddProduct.actionPerformed(AddProduct.java:104)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
.
.
.
.
.
The dots are just to represent more and more lines of errors.



Here are the details for the product table

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFN5m.png
```

Comment: Could you show the definition of Product table?

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful to print entire stacktrace here

Comment: @jnr try checking it now that i've printed part of the stack trace

Comment: @J.Lee i've attached an image to the table info

Comment: Could you modify your code to capture string that causes the exception and print it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the query that i was using.

Instead of this

```
String query = "Insert into Product values ( ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ?)";
```

I changed it to this

```
String query = "Insert into Product (P_ID,C_ID,P_Name,Price,Tax,Quantity) values ( ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ?)";
```

Now the code works flawlessly.
Thank you everyone who tried to help me, really appreciate it.